# Show TinyMCE when use is logged in otherwise not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I want TinyMCE applied on a TextArea when user role is admin otherwise show normal TextArea.

How do I do that?

Is there TinyMCE server side command for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the current user's membership in a role and then enable TinyMCE for a given textarea with this sort of approach:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator")) {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#mytextarea').tinymce({
                // tinymce config
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

You may also want to do the role check in your controller and pass the value as part of a ViewModel or the ViewBag.

Comment: gibson thanks for the reply. tinymce config meaning TinyMCE init code there? . I will test it.